# how to make the contents of home page to change when signUp with user page in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eventemitter

The contents of home page and user page are displayed on the home page itself.
In the header section i have SignIn and SignUp form from home.html.
I have another `Signup form` from user page, where in i have 3 buttons, `signUp with facebook`, `signUp with google` and `SignUp` with name, email and password.
When i signUp using `signUp with facebook`, `signUp with google`, the conents of home page change from `SignIn and SignUp` to `User and SignOut`, and the SignUp form of user page gets hidden.

But this case doesnt work when i give just `signUp` using name, email and password.

I have used emit emitter as well, but that doesnt work with just SignUp. Can anyone help.

Home.html:

```
<ul>
<li class="signUp" *ngIf = "loggedIn">{{userName}}</li>
<li class="signIn" (click)="signOut()" *ngIf = "loggedIn">Sign Out</li>
<li class="signUp" (click)="openSignUp(user)"  *ngIf = "!loggedIn">Sign Up</li>
<li class="signIn" (click)="openSignIn(logedin)"  *ngIf = "!loggedIn">Sign In</li>
</ul>
```

User.html:

```
<div class="favourate" *ngIf="!loggedIn">
    <h1>User</h1>
    <hr />
    <div class="backImage">
      <form name="signUpForm" class="signUpForm" #signUpForm="ngForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
          <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input">
          <mat-form-field> 
            <mat-icon>perm_identity</mat-icon>
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" #Name="ngModel" required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input">
          <mat-form-field> 
            <mat-icon>email</mat-icon>
            <input matInput type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" #Email="ngModel" pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input">
          <mat-form-field> 
            <mat-icon>lock</mat-icon>
            <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" #Password="ngModel" required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>          
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

User.ts:

```
this.ApiService
      .checklogin()
      .subscribe(
        user  => {
          this.loggedIn = localStorage.getItem("loggedin");
          this.user_id = user.data[0].user_id;
          this.userName = user.data[0].name;
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      newUser(user,_id) {
        this.isLoadingSignUp = true;
        user.role_id = this._id 
        var data = {
          "user":{
          email:user.email,
          password:user.password,
          active:user.active,
          role_id:this._id,
          name:user.name
           }     
        }
        this.ApiService
            .signUp(data)
            .subscribe(
              signUser => {
                  this.userName = user.name;
                  localStorage.setItem('loggedin', 'true');
                  this.loggedIn = true;
                  this.isLoadingSignUp = false;
                  this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                  this.toasterService.pop('success', 'SignUp Successfully');
                  this.ApiService.getUserData(user.data);
               }, error => {
                  this.isLoadingSignUp = false;
                  this.ApiService.getUserData(error);
                  if(error.data && error.data.length > 0) {
                    this.toasterService.pop('error', error.data);
                  } else {
                    this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Something went wrong!');
                  }
               })
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Observable` and `subject` to communicate between different components.

You should do this using a service.

**Create a service called `SignUpService` which creates a new `subject` for indicating signin**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class SignUpService {
  private signInSource = new Subject<string>();

  signinDone$ = this.signInSource.asObservable();

  signIn() {
    this.signInSource.next();
  }
}
```

**Call that `subject` in `signIn component`**

```
import { SignInService }     from './signin.service';

@Component({
})
export class SignInComponent {
    this.SignInService.signIn();
}
```

**Recieve that event in `Header component`**

```
import { SignInService }  from './signin.service';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnDestroy {
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private signInService: SignInService) {
    this.subscription = signInService.signinDone$.subscribe(
      signin => {
        alert('came here')
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: U mean i must create a new service?

Comment: you can either create a new service, or can use an old service if you have one

Comment: i have one api.service.. i can use in that only?

Comment: i have pasted in my services but not working properly, i mean hope i am doing wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165533/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-sravan).

Answer (score 1):

as per your requirement and project flow structure, you can take help from your browser. 
that means every time when user signIn or signUp using facebook or google. you can store a unique value in browser local storage. and can retrieve that or use that to check from where a user has loggedIn. that value can be simply used in ngIf conditions. like when to show and when not to show.

I hope you understood what I meant to say.

Comment: ya, the same way i have used, it is working with those, but not with only SignUp

Comment: use different local storage value for signUp don't use the same. and in ngIf for singUp, you can check for both values.

Comment: ya, i have alrady used *ngIf="!loggedIn", so if i use one more localstorage value, then *ngIf="!loggedIn || other name", should i write this?

Comment: yes, but I don't know why you have written this.loggedIn = true; in signUp API service. it is already setting it true don't set that value deliberately.

Comment: ya ok il remove that

Comment: so there is only one solution now, distinguish the sigUp process, like facebook, google or simple one. and use this in ngIf.

Comment: like how? the problem is i wanna give connection from one page to other so i am not getting how to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165531/discussion-between-hrishikesh-kale-and-bhrungarajni).

Comment: the logic you thought me was helpful but it didnt work for me. Thank you